# How to integrate a CTE query in Entity Framework 5

Tags: common-table-expression, entity-framework-5

I have an SQL query that I have written using CTE. Now, I am moving the repository to use Entity Framework 5.

I am at a loss as to how to integrate (or rewrite) the CTE-based query using Entity Framework 5.

I am using POCO entities with the EF5 and have a bunch of Map classes. There is no EDMX file etc.

I feel like a total noob right now and would appreciate any help pointing me in the right direction.

The CTE query is as following

```
WITH CDE AS
(
    SELECT * FROM collaboration.Workspace AS W WHERE W.Id = @WorkspaceId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT W.* FROM collaboration.Workspace AS W INNER JOIN CDE ON W.ParentId = CDE.Id AND W.ParentId <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
)
SELECT
    W.Id AS Id,
    W.Name AS Name,
    W.Description AS Description,
    MAX(WH.ActionedTimeUtc) AS LastUpdatedTimeUtc,
    WH.ActorId AS LastUpdateUserId
FROM
    collaboration.Workspace AS W
    INNER JOIN
    collaboration.WorkspaceHistory AS WH ON W.Id = WH.WorkspaceId
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT TOP 10
            CDE.Id
        FROM
            CDE
            INNER JOIN
            collaboration.WorkspaceHistory AS WH ON WH.WorkspaceId = CDE.Id
        WHERE
            CDE.Id <> @WorkspaceId
        GROUP BY
            CDE.Id,
            CDE.ParentId,
            WH.ActorId,
            WH.Action
        HAVING
            WH.ActorId = @UserId
            AND
            WH.Action <> 4
        ORDER BY
            COUNT(*) DESC
    ) AS Q ON Q.Id = WH.WorkspaceId
GROUP BY
    W.Id,
    W.Name,
    W.Description,
    WH.ActorId
HAVING
    WH.ActorId = @UserId
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must create stored procedure for your SQL query (or use that query directly) and execute it through `dbContext.Database.SqlQuery`. You are using code-first approach where you don't have any other options. In EDMX you could use mapped table valued function but code-first doesn't have such option yet.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav. That is what I have ended up doing. I am double minded about creating a new entity for the returned results. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: Or is that what Complex Types are used for?

Comment: You don't need to map any entity or complex type. Just create class with properties with same names as columns in your result set and use it as generic argument for `SqlQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

I have built a stored procedure which takes array of ids as input parameter and return data table using recursive cte query [Take a look at the code here it's using EF and code first approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48870595/8618595)