# How to retrieve result from a stored procedure using entity-framework in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure `sp_ValidateUser` which returns two columns `UserID` and `RoleID`.

I created used the Function Import with the following settings:

[image]

MVC code:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index(tblUser user)
{
    SchoolDBEntities usersEntities = new SchoolDBEntities();
    int? userId = usersEntities.fnValidateUser(user.Username, user.Password).FirstOrDefault(); //Check if correct username and password

    string message = string.Empty;

    if (userId.RoleID == 1) //returns error
    {
        //Redirect to URL
    }

    return View(user);
}
```

How can I retrieve both `RoleID` and `UserID` from the return collection of `sp_ValidateUser_Result`?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Just look at the result of `usersEntities.fnValidateUser(user.Username, user.Password).FirstOrDefault()`. It's not an `int?`. The returned type will give you a hint what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

As you are already returning a complex type called `sp_ValidatUser_Result` from your method call for stored procedure which you generated using **Function Import**, you should be able to get the result like:

```
sp_ValidatUser_Result result = usersEntities.fnValidateUser(user.Username, user.Password).FirstOrDefault(); //Check if correct username and password

string message = string.Empty;

if (result != null && result.RoleID == 1)
{
     //Redirect to URL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have built a stored procedure which takes array of ids as input parameter and return data table(in my case was only ids of childs elements in self-referencing table) [Take a look at the code here it's using EF and code first approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48870595/8618595)